# Python - Async HTTP request, Blocking at the end for complete response HTTP (urllib3, requests, threading)

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-requests

I'm not really concerned with the method used whether it be urllib3, requests, or even threading.  I am using a software library which has the notion of "tasks".  I am hooking the beginTask and taskComplete functions as follows:

```
class addon:


    def __init__(self):
        self.passed_check={}

    def beginTask(self, task):

            r = requests.get("https://website.com/?name="+task.attribute);
            result = json.loads(r.text)
            if(result['attr']==1):
                self.passed_check[task.id]=1


    def taskComplete(self, task):

        if(self.passed_check[task.id]):
            #do SOMETHING
        else:
            #do Something else
```

The flow of the code is:

1. Library handles initial state of task. - Handled by the library.
2. beginTask function runs. - I overrode it with my addon, normally it's blank.
3. IO intensive task begins. - Handled by the native library.
4. taskComplete function runs. - I overrode it with my addon, normally it's blank.

The issue I have with the above code is my call to **requests** is blocking IO which therefore blocks the rest of the task.  This is not correct but I really want to do something like.

```
class addon:


    def __init__(self):
        self.passed_check={}
        self.requests_mapper={}

    def beginTask(self, task):

            self.requests_mapper[task.id] = requests.get("https://website.com/?name="+task.attribute, async=True);


    def taskComplete(self, task):

        while self.requests_mapper[task.id].request_complete == False:
            pass

        result = json.loads(r.text)
        if(result['attr']==1):
            self.passed_check[task.id]=1

        if(self.passed_check[task.id]):
            #do SOMETHING
        else:
            #do Something else
```

Essentially I want to kick off an async call to make the HTTP request, let the library and the HTTP request run in parallel but prior to the task completing ensure the HTTP request completes so I can do my thing (which is the reason for the while loop, in theory the task can complete before the HTTP request comes back).  I also need to make sure the **entire** response is received so I can properly evaluate it prior to ending the task.  I need to block the taskComplete function.

Since multiple tasks can run in tandem I am using the request_mapper which is a dict mapped by task id to keep track of which task the request belongs to.

Here's a diagram (I can't link yet):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy4cO.png

Any suggestions.

Comment: Is the other code using `asyncio` based asynchronous execution?  If so, the [`aiohttp`](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library is designed to make asynchronous http easier.

Comment: It depeends what library you're using I guess, but most threading/microthreading/multiprocessing libraries have a `join`-type feature that, when called, will block until the tasks are complete. (e.g. in `concurrent.futures` it'd be `executor.shutdown()`, etc.)

Comment: The library is async and multiple tasks run at the same time.  My issue is kicking off the HTTP request in an asynchronous fashion and blocking that at the end.  I guess the question is how can I kick off an async HTTP request, do some stuff, then at a certain point in time block until it complets.  Imagine kick off HTTP request, calculate pi, ensure the request is done, end function.  I want to calc PI and run the HTTP request at the same time but I still want to block after the PI calculation to ensure the request completed.

Comment: My understanding is you want to make *requests* non-blocking, so you need to read `concurrent.futures`, `threading`&`Queue`, `asyncio(run_in_executor)`.